# Iterating through a 2d String array to show all combinations of given array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, iteration, nested-loops

I am wanting to try and implement a way of iterating through all possible variations of values inside a 2d array.

Similar to what can be done with a set of 1d arrays such as:

```java
String[] pos = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"};
String[] color = {"green", "red", "white", "black", "blue"};
String[] cars = {"xtrail", "camry", "civic", "accent", "barina"};
String[] home = {"canada", "british", "french", "chinese", "indian"};
String[] location = {"sydney", "goldcoast", "newcastle", "tamworth", "portmaq"};
String[] time = {"5am", "6am", "7am", "8am", "9am"};
```

and then looping through with the use of nested for loops:

```java
for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 5; b++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < 5; d++) {
                for (int e = 0; e < 5; e++) {
                    for (int f = 0; f < 5; f++) {
                        String[] ans = {pos[a], color[b], cars[c],
                                home[d], location[e], time[f]};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `ans` array holds the current iteration of the possible car.

Can this be done with the use of a 2d array instead of the 5 different 1d arrays:

```
String[][] travel = {
        {"1 ", "green ", "xtrail ", "canada ", "sydney ", "5am"},
        {"2 ", "red ", "camry ", "british ", "goldcoast ", "6am"},
        {"3 ", "white ", "civic ", "french", "newcastle ", "7am"},
        {"4 ", "black ", "accent ", "chinese ", "tamworth ", "8am"},
        {"5 ", "blue ", "barina ", "indian ", "portmaq ", "9am"}};
```

To achieve the same result as `ans` just with all possible combinations of the 5 cars at a time with the 2d array?

I understand this is not the best way to do what Im trying ot do, but I am trying to learn how these arrays can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the transpose of the array OR traverse the array in that order. Similar to this code

```java
import java.util.*;

class test {
    static String[][] travel = { 
        { "1 ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 " }, 
        { "green ", "red ", "white ", "black ", "blue " },
        { "xtrail ", "camry ", "civic ", "accent ", "barina " },
        { "canada ", "british ", "french", "chinese ", "indian " },
        { "sydney ", "goldcoast ", "newcastle ", "tamworth ", "portmaq " }, 
        { "5am", "6am", "7am", "8am", "9am" } 
    };

    public static void generate(String travel[][]) {
        _generate(travel, 0, new String[travel.length]);
    }

    private static void _generate(String travel[][], int level, String ans[]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < travel[level].length; i++) {
            ans[level] = travel[level][i];
            if (level + 1 == travel.length) {
                /* consume the answer here */
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ans));
            } else {
                _generate(travel, level + 1, ans);
            }
        }
    }

    /* usage */
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        generate(travel);
    }
}
```

A more generic answer would be to use consumer interface and generalize this solution

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

class test {
    static String[][] travel = { 
        { "1 ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 " }, 
        { "green ", "red ", "white ", "black ", "blue " },
        { "xtrail ", "camry ", "civic ", "accent ", "barina " },
        { "canada ", "british ", "french", "chinese ", "indian " },
        { "sydney ", "goldcoast ", "newcastle ", "tamworth ", "portmaq " }, 
        { "5am", "6am", "7am", "8am", "9am" } 
    };

    public static void generate(String travel[][], Consumer<String[]> f) {
        _generate(travel, 0, new String[travel.length], f);
    }

    private static void _generate(String travel[][], int level, String ans[], Consumer<String[]> f) {
        for (int i = 0; i < travel[level].length; i++) {
            ans[level] = travel[level][i];
            if (level + 1 == travel.length) {
                f.accept(ans);
            } else {
                _generate(travel, level + 1, ans, f);
            }
        }
    }

    /* usage */
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        generate(travel, x -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by finding permutations for each column w.r.t the row and storing it in a 1D array `outputRow`.

This is achieved by recursively calling the `print` function as shown below:

```
public class StackOverflow 
{    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[][] travel = 
        {     
                { "1 ", "green ", "xtrail ", "canada ", "sydney ", "5am" },
                { "2 ", "red ", "camry ", "british ", "goldcoast ", "6am" },
                { "3 ", "white ", "civic ", "french", "newcastle ", "7am" },
                { "4 ", "black ", "accent ", "chinese ", "tamworth ", "8am" },
                { "5 ", "blue ", "barina ", "indian ", "portmaq ", "9am" } 
            
        };
            
        int row = travel.length;
        int col = travel[0].length;
        
        String[] outputRow = new String[col];
        print(0, row, col, travel, outputRow);
 
     }

     static void print(int j, int row, int col, String[][] first, String[] outputRow) 
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
       {
           outputRow[j] = first[i][j];

           //Recursively continue to populate outputRow until we reach the last column i.e. (j == col -1)
           if (j < col - 1) 
               print(j + 1, row, col, first, outputRow);               

           // We have reached the last column (j == col -1), so we print the current permutation.
           if (j == col - 1) 
           {
               for (int k = 0; k < col; k++)
                   System.out.print(" " + outputRow[k]);                   
               System.out.println();                   
           }
        }
     }
}
```

1. Here we create 1D String array named `outputRow` and pass it as one of the parameters to the `print` function.
2. `print` function processes one column per recursion and keeps on saving it in the `outputRow` array.
3. The column processing starts from `j == 0` which is the first argument passed to `print` function.
4. When it reaches the last column i.e. `j == col - 1;` then the current row permutation is printed.

The above 4 points represent 1 recursion cycle for each unique permutation in a row. This cycle is repeated for all rows in the 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to solve it by inputting your 2D array this way:

```
String[][] travel = {
        { "1", "2", "3" },
        { "green", "red", "white" },
        { "xtrail", "camry", "civic" }
};
```

The solution for a fixed size 2D array (I reduced the size to 3 for explanation purpose. The way to solve it doesn't change) is:

```
for (String str : travel[0]) {
    for (String str1 : travel[1]) {
        for (String str2 : travel[2]) {
            String[] ans = { str, str1, str2 };
            System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ans));
        }
    }
}
```

For generic solution, you can create a recursive function, like below:

```
static void addOps(String[] ans, String[][] travel, int i) {
    if (i == travel.length) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ans));
    } else if (i < travel.length) {
        for (String str : travel[i]) {
            ans[i] = str;
            addOps(ans, travel, i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

then invoke it from main method:

```
String[] ans = new String[travel.length];
addOps(ans, travel, 0);
```